# How do you change the width/height style for the automatically generated canvas tag from three.js?

Tags: canvas, three.js

It seems that even if I set a global style for canvas, the three.js generated canvas tag will force its own style, thus overriding the defined canvas style. Is there a way to somehow change the width/height of that to 100%?

I've tried `container.width/.height` for setSize, but currently reverting to `window.innerWidth/Height`

http://designs.playgami.com/Anonymous/7d1afa05-5a73-4a17-b5ee-9e84664dacc7

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Code is taken from the [Three.js docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene) as you did not provide your own (adding that may help)**

The width and height of the canvas element generated by your code is set in the code itself. It is usually the `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` values. See the example below taken from the [Three.js docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene)

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

the line with `renderer.setSize` is the line where the canvas's width and height is set to the the same as the window's, but you can change this by inputting custom values, or having it use the width of a parent element which can be set in your CSS.

For example:

```
const sizeControlElem = document.querySelector('#containingElement');
WIDTH = sizeControlElem.getBoundingClientRect().width;
HEIGHT = sizeControlElem.getBoundingClientRect().height;

renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

You may also have a resize function running that could be resizing the canvas every time the window is resized which may also be overriding any styles you set, so you will need to update that too (like the below).

```
function handleWindowResize() {
    WIDTH = sizeControlElem.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    HEIGHT = sizeControlElem.getBoundingClientRect().height;

    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize, false);
```

Comment: Hi! I think your solution only works for exact defined pixel values, as the width returns 0 for a 100% width element. The problem I am asking for solutions for: I'd like to do 100%,100% of parent element